# Enabling HTML5 cache manifest in Poltergeist/PhantomJS tests

Tags: ruby, html, caching, phantomjs, poltergeist

My app is using HTML5 cache manifest file and caches several js/css/html files on the client side. We are having problems with Poltergeist testing - same tests run with Selenium pass. With Poltergeist the first test passes (the files are not yet cached) but the second and all the rest fail, the page is blank as if the cache is not working. I tried to enable the [PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference) disk cache by passing options to [Poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#customization), in test_helper.rb (Rails' Test::Unit) I declared the poltergeist driver as:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(MyRailsAppName, { phantomjs_options: ['--disk-cache=true' ] } )
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

But this doesn't help. Any ideas?

**[edit]:** don't know if this is relevant but when I pause the test in the failing run and manually visit the page with cached content with

```
visit '/mobile'
=> {"status"=>"fail"}
```

status is failing, but when I visit a non-cached page, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so guys at PhantomJS are working on e[nabling localStorage support](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/404), it hasn't been merged yet.